# How does acr122u differs between HCE and Ultralight cards

Tags: java, nfc, smartcard-reader, hce, acr122

I'm developing java application with nfctools library and I'm using ACR 122U nfc reader. The problem is that app needs to tell if it's communicating with smartphone over HCE or if it's Ultralight C card.
Is it possible for reader to recognize either one or other.

Tnx in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible by observing the ATR.

Comment: Thank you, your answer was very helpfull, i've noticed that android phone and ultralight card give different ATR values. I've managed to get card UID with InListPassiveTargetResp object in IsoDepTamaCommunicator class which is part of hce package in nfc tools library. Is this a good approach?